# Py4JJavaError An error occurred while calling o37.load. : net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeSQLException: JDBC driver encountered communication error

Tags: apache-spark, jdbc, pyspark, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-connector

I am trying to connect (PySpark + Snowflake) been continuously getting the error.

I am using PySpark 3.1, JDBC and Spark_Snowflake jar files also placed in Classpath. Not sure why I am getting the following error.

**Code:**

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
sc = SparkContext("local", "Test App")
spark = SQLContext(sc)
spark_conf = SparkConf().setMaster('local').setAppName('Testing Spark SF')
sfOptions = {
  "sfURL" : "<account_identifier>.snowflakecomputing.com",
  "sfUser" : "<user_name>",
  "sfPassword" : "<password>",
  "sfDatabase" : "<database>",
  "sfSchema" : "<schema>",
  "sfWarehouse" : "<warehouse>"
}

SNOWFLAKE_SOURCE_NAME = "net.snowflake.spark.snowflake"

df = spark.read.format(SNOWFLAKE_SOURCE_NAME) \
  .options(**sfOptions) \
  .option("query",  "select 1 as my_num union all select 2 as my_num") \
  .load()

df.show()
```

**Error:**

> Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o37.load. :
> net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeSQLException: JDBC driver
> encountered communication error. Message: Exception encountered for
> HTTP request: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: No trusted
> certificate found.  at
> net.snowflake.client.jdbc.RestRequest.execute(RestRequest.java:284)
> at
> net.snowflake.client.core.HttpUtil.executeRequestInternal(HttpUtil.java:639)
> at
> net.snowflake.client.core.HttpUtil.executeRequest(HttpUtil.java:584)
> at
> net.snowflake.client.core.HttpUtil.executeGeneralRequest(HttpUtil.java:551)
> at
> net.snowflake.client.core.SessionUtil.newSession(SessionUtil.java:587)
> at
> net.snowflake.client.core.SessionUtil.openSession(SessionUtil.java:285)
> at net.snowflake.client.core.SFSession.open(SFSession.java:446)     at
> net.snowflake.client.jdbc.DefaultSFConnectionHandler.initialize(DefaultSFConnectionHandler.java:104)
> at
> net.snowflake.client.jdbc.DefaultSFConnectionHandler.initializeConnection(DefaultSFConnectionHandler.java:79)
> at
> net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeConnectionV1.initConnectionWithImpl(SnowflakeConnectionV1.java:116)
> at
> net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeConnectionV1.(SnowflakeConnectionV1.java:96)
> at
> net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeDriver.connect(SnowflakeDriver.java:172)
> at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)     at
> java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)    at
> net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.JDBCWrapper.getConnector(SnowflakeJDBCWrapper.scala:209)
> at
> net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.SnowflakeRelation.$anonfun$schema$1(SnowflakeRelation.scala:60)
> at
> net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.SnowflakeRelation$$Lambda$866/22415031.apply(Unknown
> Source)     at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)     at
> net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.SnowflakeRelation.schema$lzycompute(SnowflakeRelation.scala:57)
> at
> net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.SnowflakeRelation.schema(SnowflakeRelation.scala:56)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:449)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:325)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.$anonfun$load$3(DataFrameReader.scala:307)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader$$Lambda$858/5135046.apply(Unknown
> Source)     at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)     at
> org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:307)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:225)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)     at
> py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)    at
> py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
> at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)    at
> py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
> at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)   at
> py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)  at
> java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
> sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: No trusted certificate
> found   at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:198)
> at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1958)
> at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:322)     at
> sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:316)    at
> sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1526)
> at
> sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:215)
> at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1024)
> at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:954)
> at
> sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1065)
> at
> sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1384)
> at
> sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1412)
> at
> sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1396)
> at
> net.snowflake.client.jdbc.internal.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:436)

Comment: It's obvious that you are having issues with SSL certificate since you get `SSLHandshakeException` and `No trusted certificate found`.

Comment: How do can I resolve this issue.@VladSiv

Comment: Try adding `"sfSSL":  "on"` in your `sfOptions`. Not sure it that will resolve it, but try it.

Comment: Added @VladSiv, but error still same :
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: No trusted certificate found

Comment: Do you have a proxy in between? This usually happens when you have a proxy in between (especially a proxy that does SSL inspection, which Snowflake doesn't supports). The easiest way to test is to run [SnowCD](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/snowcd.html) based on the URLs returned from [SYSTEM$WHITELIST](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/ocsp.html#ocsp-configuration)

Answer (score 0):

It's obvious you have issues with the SSL certificate. You can override that temporarily.

```
sfOptions = {
   ...
   "sfSSL" : "false",
}
```

However, you can check if you access Snowflake through a proxy.
You will need to import proxy's certificate and include it inside your cacerts.
the default location of cacerts of your running java version. you can locate it inside the java home directory under lib/security.

```
keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias cert_ssl -file proxy.cer -noprompt -storepass changeit -keystore cacerts
```